# Moving existing MongoDb deployment to directoryperdb by moving files instead of dump/restore

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I'm currently trying to move my existing MongoDb deployment to the [`--directoryperdb`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-directoryperdb) option to make use of different, mounted volumes. In the docs this is achieved via mongodump and restore, however on a large database with over 50GB compressed data this takes a really long time and indices need to be completely rebuilt.
Is there a way to move the WiredTiger files inside the current `/data/db` path, just how you would when just changing the db path? I've tried copying the corresponding `collection-` and `index-` files into their subdirectory, which doesn't work. Creating dummy collections and replacing them with the old files and then running `--repair` works but I don't know how long it takes since I only tested it with a few docs large collection, this also seems very hacky with a lot of things that could go wrong (for example data loss).

Any advice on how to do this, or is this something that simply should not be done?

Comment: If this is a replica set you might try to wipe and resync one of the nodes

Comment: I do not expect it to be possible for you to move the files externally to the database.

Comment: +1 to what Joe said except I would suggest provisioning an additional node and configuring it with directory per db.

Comment: Alright this definetly works, however indexes etc. still need to be rebuilt. Is there a performance gain between this and using dump/restore?